# two parameter equation to approximate torque v.s rotor speed curve of AC induction motors

Tags: motors

Like the title states, I am looking for a way to approximate the torque vs rotor speed curve of an AC induction motor using the standard specs given in a specs sheet:

- LRA
- Pull-up torque
- break down torque
- rated torque
- torque = 0 at synchronous speed

I am trying to approximate with least squares. I don't know what two parameter equation would be the best way to go with.